# If $\sin A = \sin B$ and $\cos A = \cos B$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin A = \sin B$ and $\cos A = \cos B$. Then what is relation between $A$ and $B$. How do i do this? Which theorem to use here?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen the unit circle?

Answer (score 5):

If the sine and cosine both agree at $A$ with their values at $B$, then $(\cos A,\sin A)$ is the same point on the unit circle as $(\cos B,\sin B)$, so $A$ and $B$ differ by a multiple of $2\pi$ radians or of $360^\circ$.  One may have $A=B$ or $A=B\pm360^\circ$ or $A = B\pm2\cdot 360^\circ$ or $A = B\pm3\cdot 360^\circ$, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) ,

We need either $\sin\dfrac{A+B}2=\cos\dfrac{A+B}2=0$ which is impossible as $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=?$

else $\sin\dfrac{A-B}2=0\implies\dfrac{A-B}2=m\pi$ where $m$ is any integer

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using the addition formula for sine:
$$(\sin A = \sin B) \wedge (\cos A = \cos B) \implies \sin A \cos B = \sin B \cos A \\ \implies \sin A \cos B - \sin B \cos A = 0 \implies \sin(A-B) = 0 \implies A - B = 2\pi k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: But, $\sin x=0\implies x=k\pi$  right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  That's what I initially had in my answer, but if $A-B = k\pi$, then $\cos A \neq \cos B$ for odd $k$. So I think it has to be the case that $A-B = 2\pi k$.

Comment: @SplitInfinity It is better to write $k\pi$ and then explain why $k\pi$ with odd $k$ isn't possible to avoid confusion.